# Making Generic Class Using Lambda Expression

Tags: java

I have the below Service class which implement retry mechanism :

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor_ = {@Autowired})
@Service
public class RetryService {

  private final RetryTemplate vcRetry;
  private final Order1dao order1;
  private final Order2dao order2;


  public void saveOrder1(OrderRecord1 record) {
       vcRetry.execute(
            context -> {
              order1.save(record);
            });
  }

  public OrderRecord2 UpdateOrder2(OrderRecord2 record) {
     return vcRetry.execute(
            context -> {
              return order2.Update(record);
            });
  }

   public void saveOrder2(OrderRecord2 record) {
     vcRetry.execute(
            context -> {
              order2.save(record);
            });
  }
```

There can be many daoBean which may uses the same RetryService class so i need to write the separate function for the individual bean.

Main Class:

```
public class OrderProcessor {

    private final RetryService retryService;
    public void SaveOrder(Order1 x, Order2 y,....) {
     
        retryService.saveOrder1(x);
        retryService.saveOrder2(y);
        retryService.Update(y);
         
    }

}
```

How can I make my RetryService class generic ?

Comment: Simplest seems to be taking both OrderRecord and Order as type parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `GenericDao` and use it in `RetryService` as below,

```
class GenericDao<T>{
    //dao operations
}

class RetryService<T1 , T2> {

    private final RetryTemplate vcRetry;
    private final GenericDao<T1> order1;
    private final GenericDao<T2> order2;


    public void saveOrder1(T1 record) {
        vcRetry.execute(
                context -> {
                    order1.save(record);
                });
    }

    public T2 UpdateOrder2(T2 record) {
        return vcRetry.execute(
                context -> {
                    return order2.Update(record);
                });
    }

    public void saveOrder2(T2 record) {
        vcRetry.execute(
                context -> {
                    order2.save(record);
                });
    }
}
```

I hope it helps!